# change the path of Product image

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, product-images, product-view

please visit [link](http://hotwheelstoys.in/2/em0113-full-package/index.php/electronics/nokia-2610-phone.html) , product image is serving from cache path :

```
media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/350x350/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/m/img26_1.jpg
```

we want to change to below path.

```
media/catalog/product/i/m/img26_1.jpg
```

i am trying following code in media.phtml but its not working for me.

```
<?php echo formatPath($_img->resize($w, $h)); ?>
```

**media.phtml**

```
<?php 
function formatPath($mediaFile = '')
{
    $main = $mediaFile;

$mainArray = explode('/', $main);
$countArray = count($mainArray);
return Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product/'.$mainArray[$countArray-3].'/'.$mainArray[$countArray-2].'/'.$mainArray[$countArray-1];
}
 ?>

<?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $dexxtz = Mage::helper('productzoom');

    $dexxtz->getCss();
    $dexxtz->getJs();
?>

<ul id="etalage">
    <li>                
        <img class="etalage_thumb_image" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')); ?>" />
        <img class="etalage_source_image" title="<?php echo $_product->getImageLabel(); ?>" 
        src="<?php echo formatPath($_img->resize($w, $h)); ?>" />

    </li>
    <?php 
        foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image) {
            if(Mage::registry('current_product')->getImage() != $_image->getFile()) { ?>                
            <li>
                <img class="etalage_thumb_image" 
                src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())); ?>" />
                <img class="etalage_source_image" title="<?php echo $_image->getLabel(); ?>" 
                src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()), true); ?>" />
            </li> 
        <?php 
            }    
        }
    ?>   
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($product->getImage());
```

Comment: there are 4 `<img src=">` in our media.phtml. i replaced in all 4 places in another site. it giving blank page now.
i know i did some mistake. please check this code : http://pasted.co/76a3aae4  and help me what wrong i did ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento Just replace `$product` with `$_product` in the code I pasted ;)

Comment: i don't know how you can post an answer before i post question, thanks a lot :-)

Comment: [link1](http://hotwheelstoys.in/2/em0113-full-package/index.php/electronics/nokia-2610-phone.html) :
 `<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')); ?>`

[link2](http://hotwheelstoys.in/4/em0113-full-package/index.php/electronics/nokia-2610-phone.html) : 
`<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getImage()); ?>`

now in link2 image is having more zoom, is there any way to fix it . we using [extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dexxtz-product-zoom.html)

Comment: @BabyinMagento what if you do: `<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured(Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getImage(‌​))); ?>` ?

Comment: blank page, please check.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento I'm not too sure as it's related to a 3rd party module, I reckon you should contact them

Comment: okay, no problem. i thought i did some small mistake again as like i missed underscore last time.
i will contact them. Thanks again.