# Need to reduce the zooming level of the image

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, zoom

please visit [link1](http://hotwheelstoys.in/5/em0113-full-package/index.php/electronics/nokia-2610-phone.html) you can see image is zooming too much ,

but here [link2](http://hotwheelstoys.in/2/em0113-full-package/index.php/electronics/nokia-2610-phone.html) its fine. how to display link 1 image  as like link2

code for link 1 :

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getImage()); ?>
```

code for link 2 :

```
<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')); ?>
```

why we are using code for link 1 is because to solve this [problem](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113563/change-the-path-of-product-image/)

**media.phtml**

```
<?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $dexxtz = Mage::helper('productzoom');

    $dexxtz->getCss();
    $dexxtz->getJs();
?>

<ul id="etalage">
    <li>                
        <img class="etalage_thumb_image" 
        src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getImage()); ?>" />
        <img class="etalage_source_image" title="<?php echo $_product->getImageLabel(); ?>" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'), true); ?>" />
    </li>
    <?php 
        foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image) {
            if(Mage::registry('current_product')->getImage() != $_image->getFile()) { ?>                
            <li>
                <img class="etalage_thumb_image" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())); ?>" />
                <img class="etalage_source_image" title="<?php echo $_image->getLabel(); ?>" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()), true); ?>" />
            </li> 
        <?php 
            }    
        }
    ?>   
</ul>
```

**script**

```
var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
var b, c, w, h, t, l;

b = jQuery('.dexxtz-bg-modal');
c = jQuery('.dexxtz-modal-content');
w = (jQuery('body').innerWidth() / 2);
h = (window.innerHeight / 2);
t = ((h - (c.height() / 2)) < 15) ? '15px' : h - (c.height() / 2) + 'px';
l = ((w - (c.width() / 2)) > 0) ? w - (c.width() / 2) + 'px' : 0;

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    w = (jQuery('body').innerWidth() / 2);
    h = (window.innerHeight / 2);
    t = ((h - (c.height() / 2)) < 15) ? '15px' : h - (c.height() / 2) + 'px';
    l = ((w - (c.width() / 2)) > 0) ? w - (c.width() / 2) + 'px' : 0;

    c.css('top', t)
    c.css('left', l);
});

function DexxtzModal() {            
    c.css('top', t)
    c.css('left', l);
    b.fadeIn('slow');
    c.fadeIn('slow');   
}

function DexxtzModalClose() {
    b.fadeOut('slow');
    c.fadeOut('slow');
}
```

we have same kind of configuration in both links.

Comment: You are fetching the product image directly from media folder so only it with full size. If you resize the image while fetching means your issue will be solved,

Comment: @Manikandan can you help me with the code ?

Comment: i have posted an answer related to it. It may help you i think so @Baby in Magento

Comment: @Baby in Magento link1is not working. shows 404

Comment: @AshishMadankar Thanks buddy for informing,  i will correct it soon.

Comment: this functionality depends on javascript/jQuery, SO please use the link2 module javascript/jQuery that may solve your issue.

Comment: @User34444 i updated the js code in question, please check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can used the following codes instead of link 1 code

```
$smallImageUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getSmallImage());
```

or

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(350, 350);
```

Comment: when i tried your 1st code, i found blank page : `<?php $smallImageUrl = $productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($product->getSmallImage()); ?>` when i tried second code, zoom problem is fixed , but [this](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113563/change-the-path-of-product-image/) problem will come

Comment: in the first code use '$_product' instead of $product @Baby in Magneto. What problem you are facing in second code

Comment: stil blank page for 1st code , please check : `<?php $smallImageUrl = $_productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($_product->getSmallImage()); ?>`  if i use 2nd code image will serve from cache path. but i want from main path

Comment: i have edited the answer check it now@Baby in Magento

Comment: i used 1st code, its displaying like this : http://prnt.sc/b03wie , only loading symbol displaying.

Comment: i used 2nd code, image is serving from cache.

Comment: IF you resize the image means it will fetch from cache only

Comment: when i follwed this `<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getImage()); ?>` it didt came from cache,
but zooming will become more.

Comment: instead of $_product->getImage(‌​) you can try getSmallImage(), getThumbnail()

Comment: i used both `getSmallImage(), getThumbnail()` but its still zooming.